# Failure when processing extension 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager, dsc

I am attempting to deploy a Azure Resource Template to a brand new Windows Server VM on Azure which includes a Microsoft.Powershell.DSC resource to the VM.

The DSC configuration file has been pushed to public accessible Azure Storage Blob container which I have verified can be downloaded from a browser accessing the [URL](https://armstore0.blob.core.windows.net/dsc/DomainController-DSC.ps1.zip).

After successfully deploying a new VM I added an extension sub-resource to execute the DSC configuration file stored in the Azure blob container mentioned above.

I cannot figure out why it is failing.

I execute the deployment using this command:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
    -Name $resourceDeploymentName `
    -ResourceGroupName $rscrcGrpName `
    -TemplateFile $templatePath `
    -TemplateParameterFile $parameterPath `
    -Verbose
```

Here is the error:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 3:56:46 PM - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines 'DC1' failed with message '{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
        "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error message: \"The DSC Extension failed to install: 
Error unpacking 'DomainController-DSC.ps1'; verify this is a valid ZIP package.\nError details: Exception calling \"ExtractToDirectory\" with \"2\" 
argument(s): \"End of Central Directory record could not be found.\".\r\nMore information about the failure can be found in the logs located under 
'C:\\WindowsAzure\\Logs\\Plugins\\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\\2.20.0.0' on the VM.\r\nTo retry install, please remove the extension from the VM first. \"."
      }
    ]
  }
}'
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 3:56:46 PM - VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error message: "The DSC 
Extension failed to install: Error unpacking 'DomainController-DSC.ps1'; verify this is a valid ZIP package.
Error details: Exception calling "ExtractToDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "End of Central Directory record could not be found.".
More information about the failure can be found in the logs located under 'C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.20.0.0' on the VM.
To retry install, please remove the extension from the VM first. ".
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 3:56:46 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list 
deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 3:56:46 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list 
deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

Here is the VM Resource definition:

```
{
      "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "vm-DC1"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('vmAdminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('vmAdminPassword')]",
          "windowsConfiguration": {
            "provisionVmAgent": "true"
          }
        },
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
            "offer": "WindowsServer",
            "sku": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "[concat(concat(reference(resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints['blob'], 'vhds/'), parameters('virtualMachineName'), '2016812162929.vhd')]"
            },
            "createOption": "fromImage"
          },
          "dataDisks": [ ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[reference(resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName')), '2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints['blob']]"
          }
        }
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
          "type": "extensions",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "dsc-DomainController"
          },
          "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
            "type": "DSC",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "2.9",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "forceUpdateTag": "1.0",
            "settings": {
              "configuration": {
                "url": "https://armstore0.blob.core.windows.net/dsc/DomainController-DSC.ps1.zip",
                "script": "DomainController-DSC.ps1",
                "function": "FileResourceDemo"
              },
              "configurationArguments": {
                "nodeName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]"
              }

            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Not sure this is related but your template passes in a configArg that is not accepted by the script.  Try removing that and see if it helps.  Also, there is a "hello world" sample here that might help: https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples/tree/master/VMDSCInstallFile

Answer (score 0):

It could be some network glitch. Have you tried deploying the template again?

Comment: Not likely. Thanks for the thought.  I have redeployed numerous times.

Comment: Version 2.20 of the extension uses the following code to extract zip file. Can you run this code manually on the zip file on the machine where you see this problem:    Add-Type -assemblyname System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($configurationPackageFullName, $WorkingDirectory)

Comment: Thanks I tried your code by downloading my zip from Azure blob storage then running.  The files extracted as expected. It must be something else.